# Access closed cursor causing force close

Tags: android, cursor

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'm getting an "access closed cursor" error in my app when I return to an activity.

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
public class TickClass extends TimerTask
{
    private int columnIndex;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (_index == 1) {
                    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IMAGE_2);
                    _index = 2;
                }
                else {
                    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IMAGE_1);
                    _index = 1; 
                }   

                String image_1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                image_1 = image_1.replace(".png", "");
                int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(getPackageName() + ":drawable/" + image_1, null, null);
                image_1_view.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resourceId));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

More specifically, the `String image_1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);` line is what Eclipse is saying is causing it.

Now I have the following code which I use to close 3 cursors when the activity is left:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    cursor.close();
    cursorCurrent.close();
    cursorPrevious.close();
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cursor.close();
    cursorCurrent.close();
    cursorPrevious.close();
    datasource.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Is this correct? Am I not doing it right? Any help would be great.

Comment: Where are you reopening the cursor?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie - You can't reopen a cursor (using `requery()`) after calling `close()`. You have to create a new `Cursor` object.

Comment: Where are you requerying or recreating the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close the cursors in `onPause()`, they are unusable after that. You need to create new cursors to use them again.

A better approach would be to use a [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) along with the [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) returned by the activity's [`getLoaderManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLoaderManager%28%29) method. See the docs for details on how to do this, or take a look at [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/).